# How do I remove 22lr bullet that's stuck to the bolt from the rifle?

Tags: rifles

I have recently loaded a bullet --which didn't fire twice when I pulled the trigger of a bolt action western field m820a  22lr rifle.  I have pulled the bolt all the way back but the bullet is stuck on the bolt even with the bolt all the way as far back as it goes.

[image]

What is a safe way of getting the bullet out?

Comment: Not an answer but I would spray it with a lithium based spray [(3-in-One Professional White Lithium Grease, 290-g)](https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/3-in-one-professional-white-lithium-grease-290-g-0381563p.html). It should loosen it up enough to get it out. Let it work in for at least a half hour. The lithium spray is far superior than WD-40. Give it a **shot**, it will not hurt!

Comment: What happens if you pull the bolt all the way out?

Answer (score 3):

22 Long Rifle bolt actions usually hold the bullet to the bolt with a spring. See the red arrow below.

[image]

That spring is pushing against the cartridge to hold it in place. If you pull on the spring out away from the action it should come loose. Be careful not to bend the spring too much because then it won't be able to pull the cartridge case out of the chamber.

The other option would be to just reach into the action with your fingers and wiggle the cartridge loose.

Comment: ok so I took a small flat head screw driver and tried to pry it out to no avail.  I tried using my fingers it's still stuck.  Then what I did was took out a screw on the side of the bolt and that allowed the bullet to go up so that it's now flush with the chamber but now the bolt doesn't move.  I guess I could screw in the screw again but I need another way of getting the bullet out that won't fire.

Comment: @MichaelCrivello do you have a picture of what it looks like?

Comment: I could take a picture but I don't see any way of uploading it to this site.

Comment: @MichaelCrivello If you  email it to me veduawoo12 gmail com I can upload it for you

Comment: Ok, sent you two pics...thanks.

Comment: @MichaelCrivello Okay, updated

Comment: GOT IT OUT...THANKS MAN.